# Access variable outside mongoose find method - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

In my node js program, I look into my mongoose database, and find and return the values in that collection - there is only one value.

```
var myValueX;
myCollection.find(function(err, post) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error ' + err)
        } else {
            myValueX = post[0].valuex;
        }
    });

console.log('Have access here' + myValueX);
```

Now, I want to be able to use myValueX outside this find method. How can I do this?

When I try the console.log above, I get undefined back - is this possible to achieve

Comment: No, because `console.log()` runs before the find operation is completed and its callback is fired. You have to change the design of the code to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To access `myValueX` after it had been assigned in `find`'s callback, you have two options, the first (naturally) is inside the callback itself, or inside a function called by the callback to which you send `myValueX` as an argument.

The better solution in my opinion is to use promises.

A simple promise-using solution is as follows:

```
function findPromise(collection) {
    return new Promise((resovle, reject) => {
        collection.find((err, post) => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err)

            // if all you want from post is valuex
            // otherwise you can send the whole post
            resolve(post[0].valuex)

        })
    })
}

findPromise(collection)
    .then((valueX) => {
        // you can access valuex here
        // and manipulate it anyway you want
        // after it's been sent from the `findPromise`
        console.log("valueX: ", valueX)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log("An error occurred. Error: ", err)
    })
```